# Selecting child text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have a structure like the following:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    ...
    <input type="radio" />
    <input type="whatever" />
    Here I have some text
</form>
```

I cannot change the structure of the HTML. I need to remove via Javascript the text inside the form, and the problem is to select it, since it is not wrapped inside any tag.

My solution (more a hack actually) using jQuery is the following

```
$('form').contents().filter(function(){
    return (this.toString() == '[object Text]')
}).remove();
```

but it's not very robust. In particular it fails on IE (all versions), where this.toString() applied to a chunk of text returns the text itself. Of course I could try

```
$('form').contents().filter(function(){
    return (this.toString() != '[object]')
}).remove();
```

but I'm looking for a better solution.

> How am I supposed to remove the text?

Both a solution using jQuery or plain Javascript is good for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You filter for `this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE`. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery).

Answer (score 2):

Try this, instead of just "this.toString()":

```
return (Object.prototype.toString.call(this) == '[object Text]');
```

You could also check the node type, but I never can remember how to do that; I'll go look it up but somebody's going to beat me to it :-)

**edit** told ya!

Answer (score 2):

If you use version 1.4 you can

```
var $temp= $('form').children().detach();
$('form').empty().append($temp);
```

It will remove all children elements, empty the form (the text..) and reinsert the elements..

the same in 1.3.x would require an additional step..

```
var $temp= $('<div />');
$('form').children().appendTo($temp);
$('form').empty().append($temp.children());
```

***[Update]*** in regards to Andrea's comment

[quoting jquery `contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

> The .contents() and .children()
>   methods are similar, except that the
>   former includes text nodes as well as
>   HTML elements in the resulting jQuery
>   object.

Comment: This looks interesting, but does it work? I don't have time to try it right now. I'd think the text is counted as a child as well.

Comment: @Andrea, both examples work in their respective versions..  updated answer to show documentations for it..

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$('form').contents().filter(function(){
    return !this.outerHTML;
}).remove();
```